# Spring JPA HQL enum "in clause" query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hql, rest

How can write a HQL "in clause query" with enum list?

Reserv. entity here:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ReservationState state;
```

Repository here:

```
 @Query(value = "select rez from Reservation rez where (:state is null or rez.state in (:state))",countQuery="")
List<Reservation> getByState(@Param("state") List<ReservationState> state)
```

Request here:

```
localhost:8080/reservation/getbystate?state=ACCEPTED&state=CREATED
```

Error here:

> antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: {vector}
>
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector}

if I remove null check from query, this query not working for null "state" requests. But I pass a state in anyway this will working.
I need to pass List parameter both null and 'n'length.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

working this way

```
(rez.state in (:state) or :state is null)
```

instead of

```
(:state is null or rez.state in (:state))
```

Comment: Why this works is beyond me... It has the same logic, just reversed and it actually worked for me. Is SQL being interpreted backwards or something?

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
  @Query(value = "select rez from Reservation rez where (rez.state is null or rez.state in (:state))",countQuery="")
List<Reservation> getByState(@Param("state") List<ReservationState> state)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, rez.state is not null. "state" values of get request  is nullable.